# Back button event capturing in "Ask Question"

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, back-button

The back button event isn't captured by `window.onbeforeunload` and isn't being handled by the `onbeforeunload` handler.

There are a few questions on Stack Overflow asking about capturing the back button with no good answer but yet if a user hits the browser's back button while composing a new question on Stack Overflow a message box asking him to if he's sure he wants to continue pops-up.

This message box is different between Chrome and Firefox and feels native.

So, what's behind the curtains?

How can I have the browser popup a message box which gives the user the option to stay on the current page (like with `onbeforeunload`)?

Answer (score 2):

> The back button event isn't captured by `window.onbeforeunload` and isn't being handled by the `onbeforeunload` handler.

Not true. Check [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/gYvwh/) with plain JavaScript - back button triggers the `onbeforeunload` just fine. Checked with recent versions of all major browsers: Chrome 18, Firefox 11 and IE9. (Copy the link address, browse first to some other site  then to the fiddle and hit the Back button)

So I fear your question is not really relevant - what you see **is** the browser native dialog.